# How to fix SQL Case Statement for counting based on hidden criteria in Cognos?

Tags: sql, case, cognos

I am trying to create a count based on different criteria in Cognos. I've seen other posts but they seem to work when the fields are visible and I need to have it work when the fields are not visible. I can make the CASE statement work when the variables are visible in the report but I can't figure out why the CASE statement work when I remove the variables.

The Cognos report that looks like this:

```
Title    Test                 Test Status  Count Passed Count Failed Count Withdrawn
Ninja    Physical Aptitude    Passed        50           NULL         NULL
Ninja    Physical Aptitude    Failed        NULL         23           NULL
Ninja    Physical Aptitude    Withdrawn     NULL         NULL         11
```

Count Passed uses the following:

```
CASE WHEN [Test Status (Condensed)] = 'Passed Group'
THEN COUNT(DISTINCT [Applicant ID])
ELSE NULL
END
```

The same goes for Count Failed and Count WithDrawn. It works. But my goal is to get one row per Title. So, when I remove `[Test Status (Condensed)]` I get an output like this:

```
Title    Test                 Count Passed  Count Failed  Count Withdrawn
Ninja    Physical Aptitude     84            84           84
```

It no longer counts the distinct applicants for each test status and counts all the applicants (50+23+11).

Desired Output is:

```
Title    Test                 Count Passed  Count Failed  Count Withdrawn
Ninja    Physical Aptitude     50            23           11
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? If it matters, `[Test Status (Condensed)]` is a field that defines custom groups from the original `[Test Status]`. Or maybe I need to do something else altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the CASE inside the COUNT...

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN [Test Status] = 'Passed' THEN [Applicant ID] END)
```

Think of it this way...

- For each input row, take the applicant id, but only for `'Passed'` *(`ELSE NULL` is implicit)*
- Then count them *(`NULL` gets ignored)*

You can then have a separate field that counts `Failed`...

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN [Test Status] = 'Failed' THEN [Applicant ID] END)
```